# Guest Additions copy & paste does not work on Ubuntu server

Tags: virtualbox

So I was able to do this: `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I got the warning `could not find the X.org or xfree86 window system, skipping`

When I do `lsmod | grep guest` I get `vboxguest  /*numbers*/ 3 vboxsf, vboxvideo` /*numbers*/ is actual number code that I can't remember.

When I do VBoxService --version I get 5.1.26, which is the version for my VM VirtualBox.

This is : `vboxadd-install.log`
[image]
Problem is, I have shared clip board selected, but it doesn't work! I can't use CTRL + SHFT + V to paste into my ubuntu server 32 bit 17.04 VM!

I have spent hours and hours trying to get this work, I do not want my time to be spent in vain. Any help?

So after installing gcc `sudo apt-get install gcc` I rebooted `reboot`. But I still was not able to CRT + SHIFT + V, here is `/var/logs/vboxadd-install.log` after installing gcc and rebooting. [image]
Above the line "make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVSZ.png): gcc: Command not found was just the same stuff from the first image, and under "Creating user for the guest additions" was `en0ps3: reset adapter`. and the same line "creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.

Comment: Are you installing VBoxLinuxAdditions within your virtual machine, ok? Did you follow these: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679

Comment: Apparently you have not installed gcc in your guest. See [**note 3** in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940)

Comment: @Takkat So I installed gcc v: 6.3.0 then i rebooted and I still cannot CTRL + SHIFT + V

Comment: Can you install the guest additions now? They are needed for clipboard.

Comment: @Takkat So I must re-install guest additions for gcc to work? I am using ubuntu server btw. I just installed gcc and rebooted nothing happened, I updated my original questions with a new image of what vboxadd-install.log. It still says gcc command not found. If I need to re-install, how do I delete the previous files before re-installing, or do I not need to?

Comment: Ah - now I finally understood - sorry for me being thick.  No - you can't have a shared clipboard in a TTY-only server as there is none on the server side. You could copy & paste via SSH if that was an option for you.

Comment: :( What a bummer, thank you anyway. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: one last questions, @Takkat is there any reason to even keep guestAdditions installed?

Comment: See answer - I would not need those ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a GUI-less server the shared clipboard functionality of Virtual Box can not work. A text-based server does not have a clipboard.

We may still want to install guest additions in an Ubuntu server for the following features they provide:

- [Shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) using `vboxsf` filesystem
- [Time sync](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changetimesync) with the host
- [generic host-guest communication](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-guestprops) via `VBoxManage guestproperty`
- [automatic guest logon](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#autologon) (passing credentials on booting the VM)

Installing guest additions needs access to build tools such as `gcc` or `make`.

Also see: [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

For copy and pasting commands from the host to the guest I would recommend an SSH session, which would also give you many additional features for remote guest control.

Comment: the server is not up yet (not public), and host is windows, while client is linux. So would I still be able to use SSH?

Comment: Yes, we can use SSH just fine in the local net.

Comment: Thanks for this. Good to know that I should stop searching and just use an SSH session.